# Why ODBC provider cannot use GenerateDBDirectMethods?

Tags: vb.net, odbc, tableadapter

I want to use TableAdapter Configuration Wizard.
If I create new ConnectionString and select Microsoft ODBC Data provider. GenerateDBDirectMethods is disabled. Why?

Comment: Have you tried to drag the table from the Server Explorer and drop it on the Dataset designer?

Comment: Why does it matter why? If the question you actually want answered is whether it can be enabled and how then that is the question you should have asked. As far as I can tell, that's just the way it is with ODBC, or at least for certain ODBC drivers. Obviously there is certain information that is required but unavailable. I don't know what information but knowing why doesn't really help you. Either use another provider or live without DBDirect methods.